# How to copy image from device into sandbox of application?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to copy image from the device into the sandbox of the app! Say in Library/Cache folder! How do I do it? I searched in the internet i didnt find the solution. Please help!

**EDIT:**

```
#pragma mark - ZYQAssetPickerController Delegate
-(void)assetPickerController:(ZYQAssetPickerController *)picker didFinishPickingAssets:(NSArray *)assets{
    ALAssetsLibrary *lib=[ALAssetsLibrary new];
    for (int i=0; i<assets.count; i++) {
            ALAsset *asset=assets[i];
            FileOP *fileMgr=[[FileOP alloc]init];
            NSString *baseDir=[fileMgr GetDocumentDirectory];
            //STORING FILE INTO LOCAL
            [lib assetForURL:asset.defaultRepresentation.url
                 resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset){
                     ALAssetRepresentation *repr = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                     CGImageRef cgImg = [repr fullResolutionImage];
                     NSString *fname = repr.filename;
                     UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImg];
                     NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
                     [data writeToFile:[baseDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fname]
                            atomically:YES];
                     //FOR LOCAL URL OF THE IMAGE
                     NSString *imageURL = [baseDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fname];

                     NSLog(@"%@ URL OF IMAGE ",imageURL);
                     [[ImageArray sharedImageArray]setImageUrl:imageURL atIndex:i];
                     //NSLog(@"%@ is the shared array",[[ImageArray sharedImageArray] getImageUrlAtIndex:i];
                           }

                failureBlock:^(NSError *error){
                }];
        }
        NSLog(@"COPIED %lu FILE INTO LOCAL MEMORY",(unsigned long)assets.count);

    //NEED TO STORE THE PATH OF THE SELECTED IMAGE FILES INTO SOME ARRAY HERE



}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "from the device"? Please be more specific and provide some context, e.g. a minimum (non-)working example.

Comment: I am using ZYQAssetPickerController from github for picking assets in the library. I am updating the question with the code. This actually works. I just wanted to know is there a easier solution. Since there are some custom classes , I am not sure if it will make sense to u guys. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that :

In .h, implement the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` delegate :

```
@interface yourClass : NSObject <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

In .m, create a method fired when you click on a button. It will open your photo library and save the picked image into the cache folder :

```
- (IBAction)pickFromAlbum:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *pickerController = [UIImagePickerController new];
    pickerController.delegate = self;
    pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Then implement the delegate method :

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // Get image into a variable
    UIImage *takenImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // Get the cache folder
    NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *cacheDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Save image into cache folder
    NSData *data;
    data = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(takenImage, 1.0f)]; // 1.0f = quality 100%
    [data writeToFile:[cacheDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fileName.jpeg"] atomically:YES];

    // Hide the picker
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: will notify you if it works after i try the code thanks in advance :)